# Will any new apps or data installed or added to android phone after encryption also be encrypted?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, encryption

if an android phone is encrypted, will any new apps or data installed or added to phone after encryption also be encrypted?

Comment: Obviously. That's the whole purpose of encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Android 6 used [Android Open Source Project: Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption#full-disk)

> Full-disk encryption uses a single key—protected with the user’s device password—to protect the whole of a device’s userdata partition. Upon boot, the user must provide their credentials before any part of the disk is accessible.

So all apps & data installed on the userdata disk partition would be secured by that key. One way to think of `Full Disk Encryption` is like a exterior door house key, once you can get into the house, the contents are accessible.